# If $x,y,z>0$, then $\frac{x}{4x+4y+z} + \frac{y}{4y+4z+x}+\frac{z}{4z+4x+y}\le \frac13$

Tags: inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

I have a prove of the following inequality that depends upon somewhat messy algebra.

I would like to learn how to prove it in a more elegant way.

> For positive numbers: $$\frac{x}{4x+4y+z} + \frac{y}{4y+4z+x}+\frac{z}{4z+4x+y}\le \frac13$$

Comment: Standard tools hardly works since there are $4$ points where equality is achieved in the domain $[0,1]^3\cap \{(x,y,z):x+y+z=1\}$: they are $(\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{3})$ and the three cyclic shifts of $(0,\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{3})$, so there is no hope to solve this inequality through mean inequalities, Cauchy-Schwarz and so on: this techniques locate a single stationary point, not four of them.

Comment: After finding a common denominator, cross-multiplying, and a whole bunch of juggling, I was able to show that the inequality is equivalent to $0 \le 4(x^3+y^3+z^3) + 12(x^2z+xy^2+yz^2) - 15(x^2y+xz^2+y^2z) - 3xyz$. That is, assuming I didn't make a mistake, which is all too likely.

Comment: Thanks ! I obtained the same expression. If we assume x is the smallest of x,y, and z and let y=x+u and z=x+v for positive u and v, one obtains a first degree polynomial in x with positive coefficients. I hope for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{x^2+xy+xz}{4x+4y+z}\leq\frac{x+y+z}{3}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{x^2+xy+xz}{4x+4y+z}-\frac{x}{4}\right)\leq\frac{x+y+z}{3}-\frac{x+y+z}{4}$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{xz}{4x+4y+z}\leq\frac{x+y+z}{9},$$
which is true by C-S:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{xz}{4x+4y+z}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{xz}{2(2x+y)+2y+z}\leq$$
$$\leq\sum_{cyc}\frac{xz}{9}\left(\frac{2^2}{2(2x+y)}+\frac{1^2}{2y+z}\right)=
\frac{1}{9}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{2xz}{2x+y}+\frac{xz}{2y+z}\right)=$$
$$=\frac{1}{9}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{2xy}{2y+z}+\frac{xz}{2y+z}\right)=\frac{x+y+z}{9}.$$
Done!

Comment: How did you jump from 2nd inequality to 3rd inequality?

Comment: @didgogns Because $4(x^2+xy+xz)-x(4x+4y+z)=3xz$ and $\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{12}$.

Comment: Thanks, I couldn't see that...

Comment: This is the sort of elegant, insightful argument I was hoping for when I posed the problem. It was well worth waiting for !

Answer (score 5):

Wlog, we may assume $x+y+z = 3$. So, the inequality, $$\frac{x}{4x+4y+z} + \frac{y}{4y+4z+x}+\frac{z}{4z+4x+y}\le \frac13$$

$$\iff \sum\limits_{cyc} \frac{x}{4-z} \le 1 \iff \sum\limits_{cyc} x(4-x)(4-y) \le \prod\limits_{cyc} (4-x)$$

$$\iff x^2y+y^2z+z^2x +xyz \le 4$$

Assume, now wlog that, $max\{x,z\} \ge y \ge \min\{x,z\}$.

Then, $$z(x-y)(z-y) \le 0 \iff y^2z+xz^2 \le xyz + yz^2$$

So, it remains to prove that, $$x^2y + yz^2 +2xyz \le 4 \iff y(x+z)^2 \le 4 \iff y(3-y)^2 \le \frac12\left(\frac{6-2y+2y}{3}\right)^3$$

by AM-GM inequality.

*Edit*: Well there is another cute little observation about the way OP and David H (in the comment), writes the inequality, that might reduce the calculation effort as: $$0 \le 4(x^3+y^3+z^3) + 12(x^2z+xy^2+yz^2) - 15(x^2y+xz^2+y^2z) - 3xyz$$

$$\iff 12\left(\sum\limits_{cyc} x^2y - \sum\limits_{cyc} xy^2\right) \le 3\left(\sum\limits_{cyc} x^3 - \sum\limits_{cyc}x^2y\right) + \left(\sum\limits_{cyc} x^3 - 3xyz\right)$$

$$\iff 12(x-y)(x-z)(y-z) \le \sum\limits_{cyc} (2z+z)(y-z)^2+\frac12(x+y+z)\sum\limits_{cyc} (y-z)^2$$

$$\iff 12(x-y)(x-z)(y-z) \le \sum\limits_{cyc} \left(2y+z+\frac12(x+y+z)\right)(y-z)^2$$

Observing that $(x-y),(y-z)$ and $(z-x)$ remain invariant under the transformations:

$x \mapsto x-t$ , $y \mapsto y-t$ and $z \mapsto z-t$

It suffices to prove the inequality for the case where terms in RHS is minimized, i.e., when we let $t = \min\{x,y,z\} = 0$.

Wlog, if $z=\min\{x,y,z\}$, then it reduces $x^2y+y^2z+z^2x +xyz \le 4$ to proving $x^2y \le 4$ under the condition $x+y=3$, which follows from Am-Gm as usual.

Comment: Very nice ! I wish I knew how to make Jensen's inequality useful here as well.

Comment: @Phil Well I don't know how to bring the Jensen idea into fruition,  but I edited another approach based upon a bit of algebraic manipulation :-)

Comment: Beautiful mathematics !

Comment: @Phil Thanks ^_^